# Positioning two ImageViews in a Relative Layout for all densities

Tags: android, html, layout, background

So I have a RelativeLayout where i put two ImageViews, one as the background image and the other one on top of it in the middle but a little bit towards the bottom (see picture below). I have images for all 6 types of densities. My problem is if I drag it to place it where I want it to be it doesn't look the same for all densities. [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/img2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want a background Image, set it to `RelativeLayout` then use the other imageview as a Image holder. What do you mean by "It doesn't look same for all densities"

Comment: If I drag the second ImageView to where I want it to be,  in hdpi doesn't look  the same like in xxhdpi. And I have different images for all densities in separate drawable folders.

Comment: `My problem is if I drag it to place it where I want it to be it doesn't look the same for all densities` - **where do you WANT it TO BE?**

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is if I drag it to place it where I want it to be it doesn't look the same for all densities

Assuming that the position you want is slightly down from the centre..

You should create am XML under drawables folder.. say.. for eg. shape.xml

below is the sample code for it..

**res >drawables >shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<corners android:radius="12px"/> 
<stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#000000"/>  
</shape>
```

Now in your Activity XML add an attribute to your `ImageView` and set the Background and size of the shape as follows:

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/rect_image" 
android:layout_height="150dp"   // change as per your requirements
android:layout_width="250dp"   // change as per your requirements
android:background="@drawable/shape"    // important one
android:paddingTop="75dp"   // position the shape as per your requirements here
android:src="@drawable/shape">
</ImageView>
```

You will get the shape as designed in the `shape.xml` file in all your screen densities now..

> PS: change the attributes of the `shape.xml` file as required by you..